# Get the sum of the column

Tags: sql-server

Get the sum of the `Patient` column and sort in `DESC` order without taking into account the SUM row

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
    C.Especialidad, COUNT(P.ClaveConsultorio) AS Paciente
FROM 
    CONSULTORIOS C 
INNER JOIN
    pacientes P ON C.ClaveConsultorio = P.ClaveConsultorio
GROUP BY
    C.Especialidad 
 
UNION

SELECT
    'Total', COUNT(P.ClaveConsultorio) AS Paciente
FROM  
    CONSULTORIOS C 
INNER JOIN
    pacientes P ON C.ClaveConsultorio = P.ClaveConsultorio
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a group by with rollup here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(c.Especialidad, 'Total') AS Especialidad,
       COUNT(p.ClaveConsultorio) AS Paciente
FROM CONSULTORIOS c
INNER JOIN pacientes p ON c.ClaveConsultorio = p.ClaveConsultorio
GROUP BY ROLLUP(c.Especialidad);
```